# sorting columns in data grid in dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

Unable to sort the data column grid using dojo.

```
lGrid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
    clientSort:  true,

    selectable: true,
    noDataMessage: '<span class="dojoxGridNoData">No Results Found</span>',
    height: "500px",
    rowsPerPage: rowsPerPage
});
```

Comment: This is not really a question... And BTW, which version of dojo do you use ?

Comment: we are using dojo1.3.2

Comment: I'm missing the layout and the store - Maybe this has something to do with it...